# Tensorflow says Input 0 of layer conv2d is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=4, found ndim=3

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

Here's my code:

```
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

def create_model():
    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()

    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), input_shape=x_train.shape[1:], activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2))

    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2))

    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

model = create_model()
```

the input data shape is (60000, 28, 28). its the keras mnist dataset.
and here's the error

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer conv2d_1 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: [None, 28, 28]
```

An I have no idea whats wrong with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized my mistake mnist data has a shape: `(sample, width, height)` and `Conv2D` layers require a shape `(samples, width, height, depth)`, so the solution would be to add an extra dimension.

```
x_train = x_train[..., np.newaxis]
x_test = x_test[..., np.newaxis]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Input shape
4D tensor with shape: (batch, channels, rows, cols) if data_format is "channels_first" or 4D tensor with shape: (batch, rows, cols, channels) if data_format is "channels_last".
```

The Input shape is expected as (batch,channels,rows,cols) you have given number of images.

create a variable like `image_size=(3,28,28)`
and

```
input_shape = image_size
```

... This might work for you. or try

```
input_shape = (3,28,28)
```